# get_posts( $args ) return empty data

Tags: meta-query, get-posts, tax-query

I'm writing plugin for syncing prices of WooCommerce products with external source. So I want to get products with EAN (have meta data `_wpm_gtin_code`). Whaterver I pass to `get_posts($args)` I get empty data. I'm using WordPress 5.3.2.

I dived into WP source to track why. When I print generated SQL `$this->request` at `wp-includes/class-wp-query.php:2890` I see it contains "where condition" `AND (0 = 1)` which obviously cannot succeed. This piece of code is inserted by Taxonomies called on `wp-includes/class-wp-query.php:2101-2109`, explicitly by `$clauses = $this->tax_query->get_sql( $wpdb->posts, 'ID' ); $where .= $clauses['where'];`.

I didn't dig deeper into `$this->tax_query->get_sql(...)`. What I know is that I don't pass any taxonomy arguments to `get_posts($args)`, so I don't expect it to influence the query.

How shall I call `get_posts($args)` to get all posts just of some type and status?

```
        $meta_query = array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'       => '_wpm_gtin_code',
                'compare'   => 'EXISTS'
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => '_product_code',
                'compare'   => 'EXISTS'
            )
        );
        $args = array(
            'meta_query' => $meta_query,
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
        );
        error_log(print_r($args, true)); // print args
        $posts = get_posts( $args );
        error_log(print_r($posts, true)); // print posts - empty!!!
```

Answer (score 1):

The whole problem was in `WooCommerceCategoryExcluder` (old, obsolete and unmaintained) plugin which hooks to `pre_get_posts` and adds taxonomy query to `get_posts()` args.

Maybe this investigation helps someone else trying to solve similar problem.